# Wordpress <![CDATA[ comments out my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm attempting to add a short script in the page editor, but Wordpress automatically adds CDATA tags to it. As I understand it that's usually fine, but I've been having an issue. I have it currently looking like this:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
<!--
  Some script here.
// -->
//]]>
</script>
```

The problem I keep running into is that since it's all on one line when the page is loaded, the // before the [CDATA[ ends up commenting out my whole script and it never runs. Why would this happen and how can I prevent it? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
```

I suppose it would help
Visit here: [CDATA](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/cdata-comment/2072/3)